# Perform Calculations for a Given Value of Variable in Python

Tags: python

I have the following dataframe:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UZoYR.jpg

I want to execute a bunch of calculations for a given Target across its corresponding Levels. For example,

```
for Target=T we have Level One and Two hence 
  sub1=100000-50000 and 
  div1=100000/50000  

for Target=T we have Level Two and Three hence 
  sub2=50000-25000 and
  div2=50000/25000   

for Target=A we have Level One and Two hence 
  sub3=40000-20000 and 
 div3=40000/20000   
and so on...
```

The challenge is the Targets and Level can be different each time, for example we may have T,A,B,C,D and One, Two, Three, Four, Five

I am new to Python and need bit of help with how to write the loop for this so it happens without me hardcoding values. Help appreciated.

Comment: Not so clear... is it a Python issue or a general programming issue?

Comment: I dont know how to put it in a loop.